# Why when I add @api_view to my view that I get a 403

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was following along with the Django REST Framework tutorial on Django 2.0, http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/. However when I add the `@api_view` decorator I get a 403 when I do a GET on the view.

```
GET /attendance/api/youths/

HTTP 403 Forbidden
Allow: OPTIONS, GET
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "Invalid username/password."
}
```

This is my code.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def youths_json(request, format=None):
    youths = Youth.objects.filter(attending=True)
    serializer = YouthSerializer(youths, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

When I add the AllowAny permission it still doesn't work.

```
@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
```

Any ideas? I would like to get this to work and I would really like to use the `ListAPIView`.

Comment: What are you using for Authentication? and if you `print('something')` in your `youths_json` function (before the return), does it get printed?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Omar. I don't see anything printed from the `youths_json` function if it doesn't pass authentication. And I'm not sure what I am using for `Authentication`. It must be the default which I think is `SessionAuthentication` and `BasicAuthentication`.

Comment: can you post your REST_FRAMEWORK  = {} option from your settings.py?

Comment: I didn't set any in settings.py, I went with the defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add authentication_classes. Add @authentication_classes() with necessary class. To allow user without authentication use empty tuple.

Comment: I thought by default the authentication classes are set. What do you suggest I set it to that is not in the default?

`(
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'
)`

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/

Comment: to find default authentication classes go to settings file and look for REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
And it's look like you want to allow any user to access youths_json, If I'm correct then just add another decorator @authentication_classes(())

Comment: Thanks. I cleared it in `settings.py` and it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Order of decorators matters.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
def youths_json(request):
   # code here
```

Comment: That's the order I tried. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If I wasn't clear in my previous comment, that did not solve the issue.